# How to append batch file command to a strings(file names) using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm in a process of creating a batch file to list names of all SQL scripts in a folder to a text file. My plan to convert this text file to a batch file so that I can use it to execute the scripts in the server. So I would like to have the following string appended before each file name while creating the initial text file

```
sqlcmd -S %MSSQLSERVER_NAME% -d %MSSQLSERVER_DBNAME% -i
```

This is a batch file command and I would like to be appended before the each file names. 
eg:

```
sqlcmd -S %MSSQLSERVER_NAME% -d %MSSQLSERVER_DBNAME% -i 001_ALTER_PERSON.sql
```

The code I'm using is

```
set MSSQLSERVER_NAME = "%MSSQLSERVER_NAME%"
set %MSSQLSERVER_DBNAME = "%MSSQLSERVER_DBNAME%"

set myvar=sqlcmd -S %MSSQLSERVER_NAME% -d %MSSQLSERVER_DBNAME% -i

for /r . %%g in (*.sql) do echo %myvar% %%~nxg >> D:\test.txt

pause
```

Out put I'm getting

```
sqlcmd -S  -d  -i 015_ALTER_vBOARD_PAPERS.sql
```

Let me know how to tackle this

Comment: what is `MSSQLSERVER_NAME` and `MSSQLSERVER_DBNAME`? Variable or string?

Comment: Those are variables which I'm planning to use in the 2nd batch file. Its for Server name and database name. Those two will be replaced by the actual server and database when I run my batch file to execute scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set myvar=sqlcmd -S %%MSSQLSERVER_NAME%% -d %%MSSQLSERVER_DBNAME%% -i
```

should cure your problem - `%` escapes `%`

note that spaces ARE significant in variable names, so `set var = something`will set `var[space]` to `[space]something`

`set %varname%=...` is rare -it sets the variablename (contents of varname).

Even more rare to have unbalanced `%`... not sure that will work at all...